# nslookup Non-authoritative answer wrong server

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, netplan, domain-server

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18 on a server. I setup a static IP with `netplan` using `networkd` as `renderer`. On my network, I have 4 DNS Server, here the netplan config file:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        ens160:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.X.Y.34/24]
            gateway4: 192.X.Y.254
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.X.Y.10,192.X.Y.11,A.B.C.10,A.B.C.11]
```

I add a A record for xxxx.yyyyyy.com (who pointed to A.B.C.21) on my DNS servers (It's local servers) When I run the command `nslookup xxxx.yyyyyy.com`, I got the following answer.

```
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xxxx.yyyyyy.com
Address: 192.X.Y.21
```

So why it's a **Non-authoritative answer** ? It's on the same network.
Should I add a `search` in the netplan config with the `domain name` ?

Btw when i run `systemd-resolve --status`, i got the good list of DNS Server

```
...
         DNS Servers: 192.X.Y.10
                      192.X.Y.11
                      A.B.C.10
                      A.B.C.11
```

I don't have `Network Manager`installed on the server.

If anyone have an idea to solve this problem :)

Thanks,

Comment: perhaps a router or other device is what provided you the answer here. I don't think the fact this is happening on an ubuntu really makes this general website setup question on topic here but whatever, I didn't flag this.

Answer (score 0):

"Non-authoritative answer" is expected output when the DNS server that returned the result to you is not directly the authoritative nameserver *for that domain*.